# SQL Query deleting duplicate records not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Good day. I have a query in my Java code that deletes duplicate rows in a table. Initially it worked and for a while i didn't touch the project. But on running the file a few days ago, my code was throwing exceptions. This is my code:

```
String query = "DELETE error_log FROM error_log INNER JOIN "
                + "(SELECT  min(id) minid, service_source, channel,transaction_type, provider_name,     pido_account, beneficiary_id, error_description, error_date FROM error_log "
                + "GROUP BY service_source, channel, transaction_type, provider_name, pido_account, beneficiary_id, error_description, error_date "
                + "HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 AS duplicates ON "
                        + "(duplicates.service_source = error_log.service_source AND duplicates.channel = error_log.channel "
                    + "AND duplicates.transaction_type = error_log.transaction_type AND duplicates.provider_name = error_log.provider_name "
                    + "AND duplicates.pido_account = error_log.pido_account AND duplicates.beneficiary_id = error_log.beneficiary_id "
                    + "AND duplicates.error_description = error_log.error_description AND duplicates.error_date = error_log.error_date "
                    + "AND duplicates.minid <> error_log.id"
                        + ")"
                    + ")";

        int deploy = duplicate.executeUpdate(query);
```

I get this afterwards:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS duplicates ON (duplicates.service_source = error_log.service_source AND dupli' at line 1.

How do i correct this and have the duplicates deleted from the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing  `)` on line `+ "HAVING COUNT(1) > 1  AS duplicates ON "` and have an extra `)` at the end.

```
String query = "DELETE error_log FROM error_log INNER JOIN "
                + "(SELECT  min(id) minid, service_source, channel,transaction_type, provider_name,     pido_account, beneficiary_id, error_description, error_date FROM error_log "
                + "GROUP BY service_source, channel, transaction_type, provider_name, pido_account, beneficiary_id, error_description, error_date "
                + "HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 ) AS duplicates ON "
                        + "(duplicates.service_source = error_log.service_source AND duplicates.channel = error_log.channel "
                    + "AND duplicates.transaction_type = error_log.transaction_type AND duplicates.provider_name = error_log.provider_name "
                    + "AND duplicates.pido_account = error_log.pido_account AND duplicates.beneficiary_id = error_log.beneficiary_id "
                    + "AND duplicates.error_description = error_log.error_description AND duplicates.error_date = error_log.error_date "
                    + "AND duplicates.minid <> error_log.id"
                    + ")";

        int deploy = duplicate.executeUpdate(query);
```

If you haven't made any changes and it stopped working, 1) are you sure you tested this code? and 2) has anyone else made any changes without your knowledge?

Comment: I'm guessing someone else has made changes without my knowledge.